# Is it possible to do an svnsync between a folder inside a repository and a repository?

Tags: svn, repository, svnsync

I have two repositories but I want to sync only a folder inside repository 1 with repository 2. Is that possible? For example...

- repo 1: clientA/appA
- repo 2: appA

The problem is I don't have rights to modify the two SVN repositories. My task is just to sync them both via Jenkins.

To give you more background, below are the designs of the 2 SVN repositories.

1. svn 1

   - clientA

     - appA
     - appB
   - clientB

     - appC
     - appD
2. svn 2

   - appA
   - appB
   - appC
   - appD

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Configure access permissions on the source repository to restrict `svnsync` user account to access all repository paths except the one you want to sync to target repository. The case is briefly described in [Apache Subversion FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal):

> An alternative approach is to replicate the repository with svnsync
>   after configuring path-based authorization rules that deny read access
>   to any paths that need to be filtered from history. Unlike
>   svndumpfilter, svnsync will automatically translate copy operations
>   with an unreadable source path into normal additions, which is useful
>   if history involving copy operations needs to be filtered.